# React, putting all functions in top level component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture

I am in the process of building a website in React that will become huge (in terms of functionalities).
For now, I am the only one working on the frontend stack, but later on, someone will come on board.

Now, I am relatively new to React and I thought about an approach to make it easier to change components UI without breaking everything:

Let's say I have a component like an Instagram post on my home page. What I thought is that on the top-level component that contains the post, I will have no styling at all, but I will manage all the functions that the children components will have to access. Please see the snippet below

```
const PostCard = ({ post }) => {

   const [visibleComments, setComment] = useState(false);
   const [comments, pushComments] = useState([]);
   const [loadingMedia, setLoadingMedia] = useState(true);
   const [medias, setMedias] = useState([]);
   const [postState, setPostState] = useState(post);
   const [commentToSend, setCommentToSend] = useState('');

   const { age_of_post_in_seconds, created_by, has_media, uuid, text, likes_total, comments_total, liked_by_me, bookmarked_by_me } = postState;

   useEffect(() => {
       if (has_media) {
           setLoadingMedia(true);
           fetchMedia();
       }
   }, [])

   async function fetchMedia() {
       const medias = await getPostMedia(uuid);
       if (!medias) console.log('there was an error');
       else setMedias(medias);
       setLoadingMedia(false);
   }

   async function handleLikePost(isLiked) {
       const success = await likePost(uuid, isLiked);
       if (success) setPostState({ ...postState, liked_by_me: isLiked, likes_total: isLiked ? postState.likes_total + 1 : postState.likes_total - 1 });
   }

   async function handleBookmarkPost(isBookmarked) {
       const success = await bookmarkPost(uuid, isBookmarked);
       if (success) setPostState({ ...postState, bookmarked_by_me: isBookmarked });

   }

   function handleCommentChange(text) {
       setCommentToSend(text)
   }

   async function handleCommentPost() {
       await commentPost(uuid, commentToSend);

       pushComments([...comments, { text: commentToSend }]);
       setCommentToSend('');
       setPostState({ ...postState, comments_total: postState.comments_total + 1 });
   }

   async function handleShowComments() {
       if (comments_total > 0) {
           if (!visibleComments) {
               const comments = await fetchPostComments(uuid);
               pushComments(comments);
           }
           setComment(!visibleComments);
       }
   }

   return (
       <Body>
           <Card>
               <Header
                   caption={text}
                   name={created_by.handle}
                   time={age_of_post_in_seconds}
                   uniqueName={created_by.display_name}
                   avatar={created_by.profile_photo}
               />
               {has_media && !loadingMedia && <Media medias={medias} />}
               <Footer
                   likesTotal={likes_total}
                   likedByMe={liked_by_me}
                   bookmarkedByMe={bookmarked_by_me}
                   id={uuid}
                   likePost={handleLikePost}
                   bookmarkPost={handleBookmarkPost}
                   showComments={handleShowComments}
                   commentsTotal={comments_total}
               />
               {visibleComments && <Comment comments={comments} />}
               {<AddComment postId={uuid} sendComment={handleCommentPost} handleCommentChange={handleCommentChange} comment={commentToSend} />}
           </Card>
       </Body>
   )
}
```

I think that the major advantage of this approach is the possibility to act on the Footer for example and change it completely, without having to care about breaking functions or call back.

What do you guys think about this approach? what are the main drawbacks?

Thank you

Comment: I think you have to follow this structure all the logical part even function put in the container part and all the display put in the component. just you have to call the function from  component and all the logical part done in the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using your own namespaced package with a collection of reusable react components. You can publish your package on [npm](https://registry.npmjs.com/) or host your own private registry e.g. [verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio).

Packages in registries are versioned, therefore you can rely on [semver](https://semver.org/) for managing releases / (non-breaking/breaking) changes.

Example install

```sh
npm install @namespace/components
```

Example usage

```js
import { Button } from "@namespace/components";
import React from "react";

const MyAwesomeComponent = () => {
    return <Button>Click me!</Button>;
}

export default MyAwesomeComponent
```

Components in the package should get everything they need via properties.

Comment: Hi Julian, thanks for the answer. So basically the same that i am doing right now, but put the children components in packages. 
Sounds good, but i do have very strict deadlines and i am not sure i'll have the time to learn how to make the package and release to npm.
Is my approach right in the development world? I am new to dev world and i am not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jorgio no worries - If deadlines are tight, explain the benefits of the package and the extra time you will need to create a good foundation to the responsible person, that sets those deadlines. You can then decide together on how to proceed. As of now, for a version 1, go ahead and leave the components in one repo all together. For version 2 put the extraction of those on the roadmap. 
And no worries, if you are new, you will find your way quick. Publishing packages and creating them is not hard. Go for a little google search :)